# gimp: cannot find libmypaint

Tags: software-installation, libraries, gimp

Somehow gimp "lost" libmypaint...

```
$ gimp
gimp: error while loading shared libraries: 
libmypaint-1.5.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

$ sudo apt --reinstall install gimp
...

/repeats the above for attempting to start gimp/
```

---

Noted:

```
$ less update-2023-02-25_19h44m32s.log

###>>>---  autoremove  ---<<<###
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gir1.2-goa-1.0 libmng2 libmypaint-1.5-1 libmypaint-common
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 1778 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] (Reading database ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So where did it go?

```
$ sudo updatedb
[sudo] password for hannu:           

$ locate libmypaint
```

... i.e. doe snot exist!? How come?

Well let's reinstall it... first, find the package:

```
$ apt-file find libmypa
...
libmypaint-1.5-1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmypaint-1.5.so.1
libmypaint-1.5-1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmypaint-1.5.so.1.0.1
libmypaint-1.5-1: /usr/share/doc/libmypaint-1.5-1/changelog.Debian.gz
libmypaint-1.5-1: /usr/share/doc/libmypaint-1.5-1/copyright
```

... then do the reinstall:

```
$ sudo apt install libmypaint-1.5-1
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libmypaint-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libmypaint-1.5-1 libmypaint-common
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 187 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1 123 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
...
```

Fixed!

*Apparently it got removed by an "apt autoremove", so of some reason not being listed as a dependency for the gimp 2.10 version I have installed.*